# Can highlight the current menu item, but can't add the class= to style unhighleted menu items

Tags: php, css, menu, menubar

```
<?php $activesidebar[$currentsidebar]="id=isactive";?>

<div class="span3">
<div class="well sidebar-nav hidden-phone">
<ul class="nav nav-list">                   
    <li class="nav-header" <?php echo $activesidebar[1] ?>>Marketing Services</li>
    <li><a href="#">Marketing Technology</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Generate More Sales</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Direct Email Marketing</a></li>

    <li class="nav-header" <?php echo $activesidebar[2] ?>>Advertising Services</li>
    <li><a href="../services-advertising-mass-media-network.php">Traditional Medias</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Online & Social Medias</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Media Planing & Purchasing</a></li>

    <li class="nav-header" <?php echo $activesidebar[3] ?>>Technology Services</li>
    <li><a href="#">Managed Websites</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Managed Web Servers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Managed Databases</a></li>

    <li class="nav-header" <?php echo $activesidebar[4] ?>>About Us</li>
    <li><a href="../aboutus-contactus.php">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

This is added to the current page I want to add this on.

```
<?php $currentsidebar =2; include('module-sidebar-navigation.php');?>
```

I had programmed this menu individually on each page, but to make my website dynamic I used one file and use php includes to load the file. I can get the menu to highlight on the current page assigning an id="isactive", how can I assign id="notactive" to the other 3 menu items that are not active on that page. Is there an else or elseif I have to include?

Comment: I also use twitter's bootstrap if your wonder about some of the div class elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset the array before setting your preferred index.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
     $activesidebar[$i] = "class=\"noactive\"";
}
```

### Notes:

- PHP array indices start from 0, not 1.
- ID's are meant to be unique (ie, there cannot be 2 of the same ID). Use a classname instade.